# Since I am trying to install package using npm but I am getting an error shown below, How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm-install

> rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 10867

Answer (score 0):

```
 # first this
> npm config rm proxy
> npm config rm https-proxy

# then this
> npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Again: Be sure to check whether you have internet connected properly.

or:

In my case I had to edit the .npmrc directly and add the proxy settings manually.

proxy=http://yourorganizationproxy.com:8080
https-proxy=http://yourorganizationproxy.com:8080